# Cake PHP Theme integration

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I have following html/css theme and trying to convert it to cake php theme.

I was reading through tutorials but I just don't understand it. Either css file is not working or the content is not displaying.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Shedule Me</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="framework/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
    <div class="container header">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo-text" href="#page-top">New Theme</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-scroll">
                    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!-- Header -->
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <img src="img/benner.png" alt="Banner" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3 class="title-log">Already a Member?</h3>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" type="text"/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Password
                        <input style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" type="password"/>
                    </label>
                    <input type="button" value="Log in" class="elevator"/>
                    <h3>Not a Member?</h3>
                    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="framework/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="framework/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what version of cakephp are you using? 
And have you placed the css and js files in the webroot/css and webroot/js directories and using the same directory structure as you are using.

Comment: 3.3
Though the webroot has nothing to do with it. 

And also not sure how to mention following files in the theme except the css file  ( done it using <?= $this->Html->css('styles.css') ?>)

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="framework/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?

Comment: can you provide a working URL, so that I debug this further.

Comment: what is the controller code, that is what layout are you using and what is the layout code, please explain the code in what files you are using what code.

Comment: Hi Rohit, working on my local machine. 

I'm still trying to get the navigation and content fixed still stuck in the navigation as the css is not working and the js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webroot/
  custom/ <-- custom css/js plugin folder, for example datepicker plugin
    css/
    js/
  css/
  img/
  js/
```

**CSS**

```
// load css from css folder,  example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
<?= $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min') ?>

// load css from custom folder, example.com/custom/bootstrap.min.css
<?= $this->Html->css('/custom/bootstrap.min') ?>

// load remote / cdn css file, note without http or https
<?= $this->Html->css('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700') ?>
```

**JS / jQuery**

```
// load js file from js folder,  example.com/js/bootstrap.min.js
<?= $this->Html->js('bootstrap.min') ?>

// load js file from custom folder, example.com/custom/bootstrap.min.js
<?= $this->Html->js('/custom/bootstrap.min') ?>

// load remote / cdn js file, note without http or https
<?= $this->Html->js('//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js') ?>
```

**read more http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html**